# Android WebView shows plain text

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a WebView and I load the page using `webView.loadUrl("http://myurl.com")` and the page gets shown correct on android **4.X** but while trying on **2.X**, more specifically 2.3.5 a plain text gets displayed similar to this [image]

What might be the problem and how do I fix it? Thanks!

My full code:

```
public class FragmentPolicy extends SherlockFragment implements Refreshable {
private WebView webView;
private Bundle webViewBundle;
private UpdateReceiver updateReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    updateReceiver = new UpdateReceiver();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_policy, container, false);

    webView = (WebView) ll.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if(url.startsWith("mailto:")){
                MailTo mt = MailTo.parse(url);
                Intent i = newEmailIntent(getSherlockActivity(), mt.getTo(), mt.getSubject(), mt.getBody(), mt.getCc());
                startActivity(i);
                view.reload();
                return true;
            } else {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            webView.stopLoading();
            webView.clearView();
            Log.w("test", "Could not get policy: " + description + " Errror code: " + errorCode + ". Url: " + failingUrl);
        }
    });

    loadPolicy();

    return ll;
}

private void loadPolicy(){
    if (webViewBundle == null) {

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        //does not work with webview
        headers.put("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        headers.put("Accept", "text/html");


        webView.loadUrl(Utils.getBaseAPIAddr()+"getpolicyhtml", headers);

        //webView.loadData(URLEncoder.encode(result).replaceAll("\\+", " "), "text/html", Encoding.UTF_8.toString());

    } else {
        webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
    }
}



private Intent newEmailIntent(Context context, String address, String subject, String body, String cc) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {address});
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    return intent;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    webViewBundle = new Bundle();
    webView.saveState(webViewBundle);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getSherlockActivity()).registerReceiver(updateReceiver, new IntentFilter("update"));
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if(updateReceiver != null){
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getSherlockActivity()).unregisterReceiver(updateReceiver);
    }
}

@Override
public void refresh(){
    loadPolicy();
}

public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        loadPolicy();
    }
}
}
```

**Things I tried**
*Saving the HTML to the assets folder by manually copy and pasting it there and then load the saved HTML works fine. But why cant I load it from the web?

Comment: Can you upload the code as well ?

Comment: Added code and things I tried.

Comment: That is just a two lines, by code I mean full file or more code, we can't assume other lines of your code by seeing just above two lines.

Comment: Added. The added code works fine on Android 4.X but on older devices like with Android 2.3.5 the page gets displayed as plain text showing all the HTML tags etc, similar to the image in the main question.

Comment: Maybe it is similar situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420949/webview-shows-source-html-with-loaddatawithbaseurl-not-rendered-view/54322301#54322301

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and then set webview client with your web view like this

```
 web.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```