# android -Webview shows plain text instead of html

Tags: android, android-webview

This is my sample html code that suppose to convert to html, I've tested this code on several application and it works fine. This is the code :

```
WebSettings settings = des.getSettings();
            settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
            settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            settings.setSaveFormData(false);
            settings.setSupportZoom(false);
            int fontsize=15;
            if(fontsize>20)fontsize=13;
            settings.setDefaultFontSize(fontsize);
            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            des.loadData(
                    "<html><head><style>@font-face { font-family: myface;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/yekan.ttf\");" +
                            "BODY, HTML {background: transparent;  } body,div {  font-family: myface;} </style></head><body><div style='text-align: justify; line-height: 23px;float:right' dir='rtl'>"
                            + dataC.get(0).get("tozih").replace("&quot;","'") + "</div></body></html>",
                    "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

the html is something like this :

```
<p>ok</p>
```

When I run the application, the `WebView` show me exactly the above line, it doesn't shows it as html.

Why is that? what should I do to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe same thing can fix your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420949/webview-shows-source-html-with-loaddatawithbaseurl-not-rendered-view/54322301#54322301

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried logging what is `dataC.get(0).get("tozih")` to see if it is really what you expected? e.g. are the `<` etc in escape code?

Perhaps you should try `.replace("&quot;","'").replace("&lt;","<").replace("&gt;",">")` on `dataC.get(0).get("tozih")`